# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 Service Entity field create

Tags: entity-framework, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I was trying to create a link b/w custom entity(PK) and "service entity", so i was trying to create a field (Foreign Key of custom entity) in service entity.

I am not able to create a field in service entity as it is not allowing me to customize.

I Wanted to know weather i can create a custom field in service entity ? Is there a way to create a custom field ?

I am using Microsoft dynamics CRM online instance.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to create custom fields in the service entity.

From *EntityMetadata.xlsx* in the [SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50032) you can see the following values:
[image: Service Entity Metadata]

This confirms your observation and shows that it is only possible to create 1:N-relationships from the service entity (not N:1-relationships, N:N-relationships or fields).

Comment: Thanks a a lot henrik.